# Shared memory numpy array code not working

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am new to Python and am learning multiprocessing and I am following the code in [the docs for Python multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html). But I cannot get the correct value of variable `c`.

***program1.py***

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory
>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8])
>>> shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes)
>>> b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
>>> b[:] = a[:]
>>> b
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8])
>>> shm.name
'wnsm_d69eb579'
>>>
```

***program2.py***

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory
>>> existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='wnsm_d69eb579')
>>> c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
>>> c
array([ 4294967297, 12884901890, 34359738373,           0,           0,
                 0], dtype=int64)
>>>
```

Comment: You need to post your code in your question instead of posting a link to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the second program where you are using the wrong *dtype* argument. You have:

```py
c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
```

But this should be:

```py
c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int32, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
```

Don't forget to use shared memory methods `close` and `unlink` properly when you are through accessing shared memory so that it can be freed up.

Comment: @chrslg I was the one who posted the comment to the OP that the code needs to placed in the question and I had second thoughts about answering the question at all until the question was updated -- but life is too short. When I downvote a question or answer I always post a comment as to why I did so.

Comment: thank u for the answer. i will not psoting a image next time. Another question, anywhere i can learn the rules about which dtype i should use in the first and second process?

Comment: For the 6 values you specified, you could have used `np.uint8` as the *dtype* argument. Also, see [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int8).

Comment: I have updated the question to include the source. You can edit the question to see how I entered it.